# Historical Bar Indexing in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

`'Hi Guys, when creating a strategy in PineScript, when referring to the historical bars, does the indexing adjust back through time or is it fixed from the latest bar?

For example is close[0] always the close for the current bar, and is close[1] always the close for the previous bar? The reason I ask is because I am trying to test conditions at each bar interval.

Case: I am trying to enter a buy trade if the previous bar/candle closes bullish , and exit the trade if either the trade candle closes, or if the stop loss, which I define as the previous candles low is hit.
Thank you in advance!'

```
// Define variables
var stopLoss = 0.0

// Initial account balance
var initBalance = 100000

// Calculate risk per trade as 1% of initial balance
var riskPerTrade = initBalance * 0.03

// Check if previous candle closed bullish
if barstate.isconfirmed[1] == true 
    if close[1] > open[1]
        // Set stop loss as previous candle low
        stopLoss = low[1]
        // Go long and set stop loss
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=stopLoss, qty=riskPerTrade/stopLoss)

// Exit trade if current candle closes or stop loss is hit
if barstate.isconfirmed[0] == true 
    strategy.close("Long")
else if low[0] <= stopLoss
    strategy.exit("Long")
```

Answer (score 0):

History reference operator always refers to histroical bar from the current bar. `close[1]` is always the close price of the previous candle.

Further reading [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator).